# Why causes the difference in measured time for goroutine creation?

Tags: go

Consider the following application, designed to measure `goroutine` creation latency. Assume that we are running with `GOMAXPROCS=2`.

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "time"

const numRuns = 10000

type  timeRecord struct{
    Ts time.Time
    Msg string
}

var timeStamps []timeRecord

func threadMain(done chan bool) {
    timeStamps = append(timeStamps, timeRecord{time.Now(), "Inside thread"})
    done <- true
}

func main() {
    timeStamps = make([]timeRecord, 0, numRuns*2)
    done := make(chan bool)
    dummy := 0
    for i := 0; i < numRuns; i++ {
        timeStamps = append(timeStamps, timeRecord{time.Now(), "Before creation"})
        go threadMain(done)
        <-done
    }

    // Regularize
    regularizedTime := make([]time.Duration, numRuns*2)
    for i := 0; i < len(timeStamps) ; i++ {
        regularizedTime[i] = timeStamps[i].Ts.Sub(timeStamps[0].Ts)
    }

    // Fake timetraced
    fmt.Printf("%6d ns (+%6d ns): %s\n", 0, 0, timeStamps[0].Msg)
    for i := 1; i < len(timeStamps) ; i++ {
        fmt.Printf("%8d ns (+%6d ns): %s\n", regularizedTime[i], (regularizedTime[i] - regularizedTime[i-1]).Nanoseconds(), timeStamps[i].Msg)
    }
}
```

On my server, this consistently outputs roughly a median **260 ns delta** from `Before creation` to `Inside thread`. Now consider the following variation of the main method.

```
timeStamps = make([]timeRecord, 0, numRuns*2)
done := make(chan bool)
dummy := 0
for i := 0; i < numRuns; i++ {
    timeStamps = append(timeStamps, timeRecord{time.Now(), "Before creation"})
    go threadMain(done)
    for j := 0; j < 1000; j++ {
        dummy += j
    }
    <-done
}
```

Under this variation, the same time delta takes roughly **890 ns**.

Obviously, the exact numbers are machine-specific, but the difference between the numbers is curious. Logically, if I am measuring between "Before creation" and "Inside thread", adding extra logic after the `go` statement seems like it should not increase that time, but it does.

Does anyone have a good idea for why the time increase is not occurring in the expected location?

Answer (score 0):

Go scheduler is cooperative. It can switch the current goroutine to another one only at certain points of the program such as function calls, reading/writing to a channel, etc. I expect that the difference you observe is due to the fact that the goroutines are started later (after the added for loop).

Comment: I was expecting that the second goroutine could run with true parallelism, since `GOMAXPROCS=2`.

Comment: The second goroutine could run with true parallelism but the current Go runtime can only schedule it at certain safe points. Try adding `runtime.Gosched()` after `go threadMain(done)` to force it to be scheduled before the for loop. Of course there cases when Go sceduler might distribute work between running threads sub-optimally. If you have a real program that performs badly because of it try filling a bug report.